# Better way to get the reflect.Type of an interface in Go

Tags: reflection, go

Is there an better way to get the `reflect.Type` of an interface in Go than `reflect.TypeOf((*someInterface)(nil)).Elem()`?

It works, but it makes me cringe every time I scroll past it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not.  While it might look ugly, it is indeed expressing the minimal amount of information needed to get the `reflect.Type` that you require. These are usually included at the top of the file in a `var()` block with all such necessary types so that they are computed at program init and don't incur the `TypeOf` lookup penalty every time a function needs the value.

This idiom is used throughout the standard library, for instance:

```
html/template/content.go: errorType = reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem()
```

The reason for this verbose construction stems from the fact that `reflect.TypeOf` is part of a library and not a built-in, and thus must actually take a value.

In some languages, the name of a type is an identifier that can be used as an expression.  This is not the case in Go.  The valid expressions can be found [in the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Primary_expressions).  If the name of a type were also usable as a `reflect.Type`, it would introduce an ambiguity for method expressions because `reflect.Type` has its own methods (in fact, it's an interface).  It would also couple the language spec with the standard library, which reduces the flexibility of both.